# Multiple select product attribute is not showing in front end

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I have created a product attribute(Bookcase Doors) and selected it has multiple select and in advanced attribute properties I have made the scope as Global but I am not getting this attribute at a front end.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where exactly do you want the attribute ? If you could specify the page please.

Comment: @SanjayChaudhary To the front end, I want that product attribute.

Comment: Have you associate this attribute to default or any attribute set?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa yes I have associated with one attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow given steps :

1.Login to admin panel

2.Go to Stores > Attributes > Product and open **Bookcase Doors** attribute edit page, select **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront** properties as **Yes** in **Storefront properties**

3.Clear cache and check in frontend.

4.Make sure you have selected options of attribute while creating product, if not then edit the product and select the options of **Bookcase Doors** attribute and save the product.

Let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I have done as you said but I am not getting multiselect attribute. I have updated my question with images. Can you please see and help me to solve this because it has to take too much time to do. The third image is the result of what I am getting.

Comment: @kevin : I have updated my answer, let me know after following it.

Comment: Now I have updated the question and uploaded the image. Can't I select the multiple options at the time of adding the product to cart?

Comment: @Kevin : It's not that you cannot select options or so but it doesn't make sense, why would you change the product options runtime. Changing product options on every order doesn't seem right.

Generally product attribute options are predefined while creating a product so that we can perform operations like filtering products on listing pages based on attribute options etc.